# Change the operation entered parameter by IParameterInspector or IServiceBehavior in service side

Tags: c#, .net, validation, wcf

I am validating my WCF service operations by `IParameterInspector` like:

```
  class MyParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{ 
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        Token token = CarrierHelper.ReadMessageHeader<Token>();
        //Here change the operation entered parameters or something else
    }
}
```

I want to read the parameters or values which make or manipulate in `Beforecall` like:

```
 public string MyOperation()
    {
        //Here I want to read that parameter which manipulate or make in BeforeCall
    }
```

So is there a good way or workaround to implement this approach?

More explain:

By `IParameterInspector` we can define an atrrib for each operation to check user access on that so I implemented this by `IOperationBehavior` and `IParameterInspector` , so in `BeforeCall` user be retrieved and check that attrib as operation permission (Authorization for operations) which are static as enum, but suppose each operation should to know how can be run on resources (resource security,Row level security) resource are dynamic I can't define them as static or hard code like permissions it should be read from DB per user, I think it is possible to implement this also, but I really don't know how?

```
 public class RemedyBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public PrimitiveActivity[] PermissionsToCheck { get; set; }
    public RemedyBehaviorAttribute(params PrimitiveActivity[] pi)
    {
        PermissionsToCheck = pi;
    }
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) { }

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        RemedyParameterInspector paramInspector = new RemedyParameterInspector
        {
            Permissions = PermissionsToCheck
        };
        clientOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(paramInspector);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription,
        DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        RemedyParameterInspector paramInspector = new RemedyParameterInspector
        {
            Permissions = PermissionsToCheck
        };
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(paramInspector);
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }
}

class RemedyParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public PrimitiveActivity[] Permissions { get; set; }
    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        Token token = CarrierHelper.ReadMessageHeader<Token>();
        bool hasAccess = Permissions.Any(x => token.HasAccess(x));
        if (!hasAccess)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Response to end user get failed, User:{0} have not access to operation:{1}...", token.UserGUID, operationName));
        return null;
    }

    private void SetLoggingContext(object[] inputs, MethodInfo mi)
    {
    } 
    private void CreateArgumentForInvokeLog(MethodInfo mi, object[] inputs)
    {

    }
    private void CreateArgumentForResultLog(MethodInfo mi, object[] outputs, object returnValue)
    {

    }

}
```

And Use:

```
 [RemedyBehavior(PrimitiveActivity.Search, PrimitiveActivity.ManageExam)]
    public DTO_OUT Search(DTO_IN find_DTO_IN)
    {
    }
```

Thanks in advance.